# Gradient css borders not showing in internet explorer an firefox

Tags: html, wordpress, css, firefox

I am working on a wordpress header and I wanted to have a gradient bottom border as shown in the picture below.

This works fine in Crome, but it does not seem to work in IE or Firefox though. I am not very good at css and I admit I got this code from somewhere else. How can I make the gradient border appear in IE and Firefox?

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.entry-header {
    /* The main titles links as displayed in the articles*/
    color: #F1F1F1;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 5%;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    width: 100%;
    /*The following code defines the linear gradient colors below each header - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
    border-top:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-bottom: solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #009C61 14.28571429%, #cc0099 28.57142857%, #cc9900 42.85714287%, #cc0033 57.14285716%, #0099cc 71.42857145%, #6600cc 85.71428574%, #66cc00 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #009C61 14.28571429%, #cc0099 28.57142857%, #cc9900 42.85714287%, #cc0033 57.14285716%, #0099cc 71.42857145%, #6600cc 85.71428574%, #66cc00 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #009C61 14.28571429%, #cc0099 28.57142857%, #cc9900 42.85714287%, #cc0033 57.14285716%, #0099cc 71.42857145%, #6600cc 85.71428574%, #66cc00 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    /*- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
}
```

Comment: Don't be surprised if you can't get it to work in IE, It's not very easy to get modern CSS working in internet explorer. As to making it work in Firefox and Chrome, it looks like it should work. I can get it to work in Chrome but Firefox doesn't seem to work. Try researching about [linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) in FF. I think your CSS might not be correct for firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and IE don't support gradients as the image source for border-image

An alternative way to set your result would be to use to background-images, and setting different clipping and origin for them

```css
.header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#1f1f1f, #1f1f1f), linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #009C61 14.28571429%, #cc0099 28.57142857%, #cc9900 42.85714287%, #cc0033 57.14285716%, #0099cc 71.42857145%, #6600cc 85.71428574%, #66cc00 100%);
    background-origin: content-box, border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Using padding

```css
.header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#1f1f1f, #1f1f1f), linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #009C61 14.28571429%, #cc0099 28.57142857%, #cc9900 42.85714287%, #cc0033 57.14285716%, #0099cc 71.42857145%, #6600cc 85.71428574%, #66cc00 100%);
    background-origin: padding-box, border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: This works. But since I used padding the gradient covers top, bottom, left and right. How can I use padding on the text without applying the padding on the borders?

This is what it looks like now: http://i.imgur.com/XERV9YG.jpg

Comment: The dark background can be applied to content-box, as I did, but also to padding-box. See my second demo

Comment: Nice one! This helps a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To work gradients on IE 6-9 you can use this.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
```

But it support only 2 colors.

**NOTE:** This [tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), is very good to generate gradients. (By colorzilla)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use SVG instead for full support in IE and Firefox? I would rather have all the colors in the gradient if this is possible.